# Python/Selenium button click on class does not work

Tags: python, html, selenium

```html
<fieldset class = "A">
  ::before
    <button class = "ButtonA" type ="submit">
  ::before
     Click Me
  </button>
   ::after
</fieldset>
```

I am trying to open a page and click a button on the page. However, no matter what function call I make it throws the same message telling my the class does not exist, however, I'm positive it does. I don't see it nested in a iFrame. So what am I not understanding here, also why does it throw a error for a css selector if I am looking for an html class.

I get the following error

```
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)`

File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, { `

File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)`

File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response`
    
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ButtonA"}`
```

```html
driver.get("https://www.websiteWithButton.com")

#ensure html is loaded
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#check for iFrame
#driver.switch_to.frame('PossibleiFrame')

#ButtonA is a a class that exists, I'm positive.
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ButtonA')
button.click()
```

Comment: Can you provide html source?

Comment: sure give me a moment

Comment: @GuiHva see HTML

Comment: try `driver.find_elments_by_tag('button')` to see if can find any `button` elements, if not, there mush be switch to wrong page or frame

Comment: Hey @GuiHva I will try this today and get back to you after work.

Comment: no such method seems to exist `fine_elements_by_tag('button')` never mind its `tag_name`

Comment: @GuiHva Okay, so that works. I placed `fine_elements_by_tag_name('button')` and it returns a list of three buttons that are available on the page. Next steps to try?

Comment: You can click them step by step, like ` for x in buttonlist: x.click()' to see which button element is the `ButtonA`.After you find the `index` of `ButtonA`, you can just use `buttonlist[index].click()` to click the button you want, as long as the page source unchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just give my entire solution.Base on your step

```
driver.get("https://www.websiteWithButton.com")

#ensure html is loaded
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#check for iFrame
#driver.switch_to.frame('PossibleiFrame')

#ButtonA is a a class that exists, I'm positive.
button_list = driver.find_elements_by_tag('button')
for i, x in enumerate(button_list):
    print(f'Index: {i}')
    x.click()    # you can find the index of ButtonA you want by click them step by step
```

After you get the `index` of `ButtonA`, just click it directly
`button_list[index].click()`.
the `index` reflect the position of `ButtonA` in page source, as long as page source unchange, you can access it.
This might not be a smart way, but at least you can find button element you want as long as you are in correct page.